In the Playwright web automation framework, is there a method that can help me handle elements that require scrolling to be clickable?
If the element is currently visible, such as the following:

I only need to execute page.get_by_text("target_string").click() to complete the click.
However, if an element is currently invisible:

directly using page.get_by_text("target_string").click() will report an error, and you need to slide down to display the element and make it clickable.
There are two solutions. One is to press and hold the scroll bar with the mouse and drag it until it is visible. The other is to move the mouse to the entire selection window and then scroll the wheel to make the target element visible directly.
Is there a method in Playwright that automatically helps me drag the scroll bar when the element I am looking for is not visible?

According to the docs, it should scroll automatically: https://playwright.dev/docs/input#scrolling

If you share the page and a [mcve] someone can actually run it, repro the problem and provide a working answer. Without it, it's anyone's guess as to the solution.

Actually, I have attached the link twice, but my content was still forced to modify a lot, so it can't be seen here. I'm sorry that it took so long to reopen StackOverflow. Thank you for your sincere answer. Here is the link zeitro @jonrsharpe

First narrow down values so that it will be visible in the list by typing into the field character by character, as if it was a user with a real keyboard with locator.press_sequentially().
page.locator('#textarea').pressSequentially('target_string')


NOTE: Also never click or verify anywhere purely based on text as if
the text appears on multiple places , it may perform the step at
unexpected place and incorrectly pass the test. Use any specific locator property as well with the
text.

